# problems query orderByValue() firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve all persons (*people*)  where city equal Paris from firebase database.
this is my query, is it correct ?

```
query = Databaseperson.child("persons").orderByValue().equalTo("Paris")
```

**Data Structure:**

-Persons

```
- KeyPerson1 : CKKJDJOCJJ
   -name: Peter
   -city: Paris
- KeyPerson2 : WGTHKJHHUH
   -name: Oliver
   -city: Paris
- KeyPerson3 : XVCDFBJJYF
   -name: Anne
   -city: New York
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use roles for search. Like this;

```
{ "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true, "persons": { ".indexOn": ["name","city"] } } }
```

after you can use like this:

```
query = Databaseperson.child("persons").orderByChild("name").equalTo("Paris")
```